# In the pyspark, when use .agg method, why add a star in the head of the list expression

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

The data is:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as fn
df_miss_no_income.show()
```

```
+---+------+------+----+------+
| id|weight|height| age|gender|
+---+------+------+----+------+
|  1| 143.5|   5.6|  28|     M|
|  2| 167.2|   5.4|  45|     M|
|  3|  null|   5.2|null|  null|
|  4| 144.5|   5.9|  33|     M|
|  5| 133.2|   5.7|  54|     F|
|  6| 124.1|   5.2|null|     F|
|  7| 129.2|   5.3|  42|     M|
+---+------+------+----+------+
```

I want use the means to fill the null, so

```
 means = df_miss_no_income.agg(*[fn.mean(c).alias(c) for c in df_miss_no_income.columns if c != 'gender']).toPandas().to_dict('records')[0]
```

But what I don't understand is that why the head of the list expression of .agg method should add a star, `.agg(*[fn.mean(c).alias(c) for c in df_miss_no_income.columns if c != 'gender'])`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The agg function takes multiple column parameters as it's input.  This is different from a single parameter that is a list for example.  In python, the * can be used to unpack a list object and place it's values into consecutive spots in the parameters list of a function you are calling.  For example:

```
def testFn(arg1, arg2, arg3):
    print arg1, arg2, arg3

# Normal call
testFn("1", "a", "b")

# Call using list unpacking
list_vals = ["1", "a", "b"]
testFn(*list_vals)
```

Note, a similar concept exists for dictionaries and dumping them into the keyword arguments of a function.  In that case you use two stars like "**".